# How do I activate wireless flash control with a Canon 60D?

Tags: canon, canon-60d, camera-controls, wireless-flash

I recently purchased a 430EX II for my 60D. When trying to set up the wireless flash control, I don't have "Flash Control" as an option in my menu. Do I need to perform a software update?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's because of your shooting mode. You will need to be in P, Tv, Av, M or 
A-DEP modes.

Source: http://learn.usa.canon.com/app/pdfs/quickguides/CDLC_EOS-Integrated-Speedlite-Transmitter_QuickGuide.pdf

Comment: Many thanks. I wish the 60D user manual made this explicit.

Comment: @njk - It is, but you have to be knowledgeable about the symbol legend. The star in the title of the pages about Wireless Flash means "If shown on the upper right of the page, it indicates that the function is only available in the Creative Zone modes."